# why My canvas buttons are behind the object?

Tags: unity

[image: My canvas buttons are behind the object.] I don't want this to happen. Screen space overlay no problem, but when screen space camera does this.

Comment: In the future, please use the _edit_ feature that is located below the tags of your question instead of [duplicating/deleting a question](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/167113/why-my-canvas-buttons-are-behind-the-object).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## ScreenSpace-Overlay

Rendering process:

```
Render GameObject1
Render GameObject2
Render GameObject3
...
Render Canvas
```

When using Screen Space overlay, first all GameObjects in the scene are rendered.The canvas is rendered last.

## ScreenSpace-Camera

When using Screen Space Camera, that means the camera treats the canvas like Gameobjects. U can treat it like a plane in 3D world except it is always perpendicular to the camera view direction.

Rendering process:

```
Render GameObject1
Render GameObject2
Render Canvas
Render GameObject3
```

The rendering order is from far to near to the camera.

In your case, you can just `Plane Distance` of your canvas settings. Make it smaller, so it is nearer to your camera. Thus make it in front of other GameObjects.

Comment: It is using screens space though. The problem is likely `Order Layer`. Change the number from 0.

Comment: thank you, but the overlay button is working but the screen space camera did not work when the button. What is the reason ?

Comment: @YusufYüzbaşıoğlu I edit my answer to give further explanations. If you have no other questions, please mark answer accepted.